# When the popUP closes,the input automatically erases.I want the Edittext to return with the input that was placed when the popUp button is pressed

Tags: android

My issue is that I have a popup window that does not save the input of an
 Edit Text when the popUp window closes. Expected Result: what i want is that when the popup closes, if for any reason i need to reopen the popup,I would like to see the value I placed. I have tried tinkering around with the activity life cycle and onSaveInsanceState methods,but my issues seems to not be resolved. For Some reason or another my popup Window has a LIFE of it's own. It basically creates a new popUp instance every time.

```
            public class MainActivity extends Activity {
                 private Point p;
                 private Button b;
                 private TextView tv;
                 private PopupWindow popup;
                 private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
                 private View layout;
                 private LinearLayout viewGroup;
                 private EditText etext;
           //on create method
                  @Override
             protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mainViewItems();
            onPause();
         }
              //allows me to pause session
                  @Override
              protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
            mainViewItems();

               }

                  // This method is in charge of instantiating the          
                 // buttons,textviews,  and allowing an event handler to 
                 // call     
                showPopup() method.
               public void mainViewItems(){
           b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
           tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                   b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {   
                     showPopup(MainActivity.this,p);}});

                }

         @Override
        public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

       int[] location = new int[2];
       b.getLocationOnScreen(location);
       //Initialize the Point with x, and y positions
       p = new Point();
       p.x = location[0];
       p.y = location[1];

    }






    // The method that displays the popup.
    private void showPopup(final Activity context,Point p) {
       int popupWidth = 230;
       int popupHeight = 190;

       // Inflate the popup_layout.xml
     viewGroup = (LinearLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.pop);
     layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)  
                    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

     layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, 
                                                                viewGroup);

     // Creating the PopupWindow
       popup = new PopupWindow(layout,350,350,  true); //context
       popup.setContentView(layout);//layout
       popup.setWidth(popupWidth);
       popup.setHeight(popupHeight);
       popup.setFocusable(true);
       popup.setTouchable(true);
       popup.setOutsideTouchable(false);
       popup.update();


      int OFFSET_X = -100;
      int OFFSET_Y = 100;


       // Displaying the popup at the specified location, + offsets.
         popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, p.x +    
                                OFFSET_X, p.y + OFFSET_Y);

      etext = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
      Button  b2 = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.calculate);

       b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)    
                     {tv.setText(etext.getText().toString());}});
       Button close = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.close);


            close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) { popup.dismiss(); }});

                  }


                      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a new PopupWindow each time you show it.  What else would you expect-  its a new window with a new EditText.  The easiest way to fix this is to store the last entered String in a member variable of your activity, and to set the edit text to this variable when you show the popup.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I forgot to mention that i actually did this as well as one of my attempts;however, i did not place the etext.setText(variable) in the correct method. This time i placed this in the mainViewItemsMethod() right under the showPopUp() method.